# What is the meaning and origin of “Namo Tassa Bhagavato Arahato Samma Sambuddhasa”?

Tags: pali-language, pali, chanting

What is

1. the meaning word by word
2. the meaning of the whole sentence
3. the origin

of “Namo Tassa Bhagavato Arahato Samma Sambuddhasa”?

Comment: Related: [What does the term 'Sammasambuddha' mean?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/20938/471)

Answer (score 11):

- Namo -- [Homage](https://suttacentral.net/define/namo) (perhaps from a root meaning [to bend](https://dsal.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/pali_query.py?qs=namati&searchhws=yes))
- Tassa -- [to him](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tassa#Pali)
- Bhagavato -- usually translated "blessed one" or "fortunate one"
- Arahato -- I'm not sure whether this means [deserving](https://dsal.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/pali_query.py?qs=arahati&searchhws=yes&matchtype=default) (perhaps deserving of homage) or [fully enlightened](https://dsal.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/pali_query.py?qs=arahant&searchhws=yes&matchtype=default) (see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_stages_of_awakening#Arahant))
- Samma Sambuddhasa -- see [SN 22.58](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.58/en/sujato); see also the definition for [sammā](https://suttacentral.net/define/samm%C4%81)

As to origin the phrase is verbatim in some suttas for example in [SN 7.1](https://suttacentral.net/sn7.1/en/sujato), [AN 5.194](https://suttacentral.net/an5.194/en/sujato), and [Thig 1.1](https://suttacentral.net/thig1.1/en/sujato).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the verbatim locations. I missed that when reading the English. :D

Answer (score 4):

Good householder: To extend a little the answer by good householder Chris.

Bhagavato: The Liberal, The (real) Giver, The Liberated One

Arahato: Perfect One, Complete One

Sammāsambuddho: The rightly Self-Awakened One

Meaning: It's an expression of homage and deep gratitude as well great respect (all of what is required to be able to receive his gift, the Fianna)

Origin: such, if not taken just as verbalisation. for "ritual/convention of paying respect", arises at the stage of of Stream Enter ("real Buddhist") where doubts in regard of the unexcelled Sublimity of the Sublime Buddha decays: eh. Noble Sangha.

Usually cited before teaching or receiving Dhamma and at any ceremony at the beginning.

[One](https://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/mn/mn.087.than_en.html) historical use:

> ...Then King Pasenadi Kosala, rising from his seat and arranging his upper robe over one shoulder, paid homage in the direction of the Blessed One with his hands palm-to-palm in front of his heart, and exclaimed three times:
>
> > Homage to the Blessed One, worthy & rightly self-awakened!
> > Homage to the Blessed One, worthy & rightly self-awakened!
> > Homage to the Blessed One, worthy & rightly self-awakened!

Answer (score 3):

Arahato = Ari(Enemy) - Hat(Kill). The word means, one who has killed all his enemies. (Sounds Strange right?). No!!! Buddha didn't kill anyone.
In Buddhism, no person is considered an Enemy. The real enemies are the Mental defilements/ Impurities/ Sankharas that can cause endless rebirths, and Samsara (Flow of Birth, Ageing, Disease, Death, and the suffering associated with each stage).

There are other words Arahant, Arihant, Arahat, Arihat.. All mean the same thing.